# Find number of orders for customer first month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI and learning how to perform cohort analysis with DAX in Power BI. Is there any way to find out how many times (or if easier if a customer buys more than a certain threshold) their first month?

If I have the table Customers:
ID | DateOfFirstRegistration

And the table of orders:
ID | customerId | orderDate

Let me know if any more information is helpful!
EDIT: If possible, is it also possible to plot it in a matrix with customers in each row and month 1 through 3 in the columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this measure in a table visualization together with customer ID:

```
First Month Purchases = 
VAR _registration = 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'customers'[DateOfFirstRegistration] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( 'orders' ) , 
        DATESINPERIOD ( 
            'orders'[orderDate] , 
            _registration , 
            1 , 
            MONTH 
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get it to show up in the table visualization ( it is just one number), but I will try again. Would it maybe be possible to put it in a matrix and have the rows per customers, and then the columns for first month, second month and lastly third month?

Comment: You need to use it in a table together with `Customer ID` to get the result you are after. The measure will calculate one number per evaluation context, and with only the measure in the table there is only one evaluation context. Your matrix calculation will require additional measures to capture orders in 2nd, 3rd month.